# docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '': VolumeDriver.Mount: 404 Not Found.(LINSTOR Docker Volume Plugin)

Tags: docker

I am trying to use LINSTOR Docker Volume Plugin and I am able to create the volume but getting an error while mounting the volume.

```
docker run -itd --name=test -v lsvol:/data --volume-driver=linbit/linstor-docker-volume:latest ubuntu
8e02305a8fe63a0d6b99647e8fa7a532fa9cb3565e9bb04bab718b708382f0fe
docker:`enter code here` Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '': VolumeDriver.Mount: 404 Not Found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for reference since I wasn't able to find any information about this anywhere: LinSTOR was behaving correctly but the docker plugin [`lade/linstor:latest`](https://github.com/LINBIT/linstor-docker-volume-go/commits/master) was giving me a 404 on mount, just like mentioned here.

Not knowing any go, I simply `tcpdump`ed the communication between the host and the linstor-controller and saw that after successfully calling `/v1/resource-definitions/linstor_demo/resources/` the plugin was calling `/v1/resource-definitions/linstor_demo/resources/nodename`, that returned 404.

In my case the nodes were called `linstore-satellite.nodename.domain.net`, including in DNS and in their LinSTOR definitions.

I deleted everything, made all nodenames resolvable from each of them then redefined nodes, storage-pools, resource-groups, volume-groups and it (mostly) worked: it couldn't mount the volume as xfs (from the docs I thought it would be automatically formatted, apparently it's not)

I fomatted the DRBD device (luckily mentioned in the error) with `mkfs -t xfs /dev/drbd000x` and after that it worked

Comment: Hi RobM, I am also getting the same error as 404.  What I would like to know is that do you need to install DRBD into your Docker node ?  Currently the way I setup is to separate both `compute` and `storage` node`.   How is your setup  looks like ?

I have posted my question in stackoverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67708023/running-linstor-in-docker-swarm

Would greatly appreciate if you could shed some light